# UITextField Autocomplete with max length

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Im currently trying to set a max length on a `UITextField` which works fine as per the UITextField delegate method

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let currentText = textField.text ?? ""
    guard let stringRange = Range(range, in: currentText) else { return false }

    let updatedText = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: stringRange, with: string)

    return updatedText.count <= 9
}
```

Tthe issue im having is when using autocomplete with some text already input.

For example, the `UITextField` is set to have the content type of postal code. Everything works fine if i autocomplete a postcode `LS27 8LN` or similar from an empty `UITextField`

An example problem is if i have postcode `LS` already in the `UITextField` and i autocomplete `LS27 9AL` the updatedText in the example code is `LSLS27 9AL` which goes over my max length. The range also has location and length of 0

One thing i've noticed is if i remove the delegate method all together, it seems iOS replaces the current text within the `UITextField` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension of UITextField

```
import UIKit

private var __maxLengths = [UITextField: Int]()

extension UITextField{

private struct Constants {
    static let defaultMaxLength: Int = 150
}
@IBInspectable var maxLength: Int {
    get {
        guard let len = __maxLengths[self] else {
            return Constants.defaultMaxLength
        }
        return len
    }
    set {
        __maxLengths[self] = newValue
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(fix), for: .editingChanged)
    }
}

@objc func fix(textField: UITextField) {
    let text = textField.text
    textField.text = text?.safelyLimitedTo(length: maxLength)
}

func safelyLimitedTo(text: String, length n: Int) -> String {
    guard n >= 0, text.count > n else {
        return text
    }
    return String( Array(text).prefix(upTo: n) )
}

}
```

Them set the maxLenght you need, like textField.maxLength = 20